# Converting probit coefficients into effect sizes for meta-analysis

Tags: logistic, standard-error, meta-analysis, effect-size, probit

I am conducting a meta-analysis but the raw study coefficients are probit coefficients. I am planning to convert these to log odds to meta-analyse through the formula: 1.61 * probit_coefficient.

Q1) Is this conversion correct?

Q2) Also, is it appropriate to then convert the standard errors of the probit coefficients to log odds standard errors via 1.61*probit_SE?

Q3) And then calculate the variance for the log odds as logodds_SE^2 * sample_size?

Comment: Is there any reason why you do not want to use the probit coefficients and their se directly?

Comment: I wasn't aware that probit coefficients could be used for meta-analysis, as they are not typical standardised effect sizes that can be easily interpreted. E.g. I thought effect sizes for meta-analysis need to be Cohen's d, r, Fisher's Z, or log odds (which I would likely convert to odds ratios for interpretation).

Comment: You can use anything for which you have a standard error. The ones you quote are the ones which are most often seen.